# RSA-OAEP Padding scheme

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key, oaep

Honestly I'm really confused about padding in RSA scheme. I don't study computer science, and I'm a beginner learning cryptography (self-taught). Can anyone  give me suggestions?

Comment: Padding schemes in RSA remove otherwise exploitable mathematical structure in ciphertext and signature. That should not be too confusing.

Comment: @DannyNiu a source to learn more detail ?

Comment: Have you tried to read David Pointcheval's [_How to Encrypt Properly with RSA_](ftp://ftp.di.ens.fr/pub/users/pointche/Papers/2002_cryptobytes.pdf) ?

Comment: @fgrieu nope.but i have read about RSA primitive

Comment: A note about stackexchange in general: "Can anyone give me suggestions?" is not a good question format (unless you're on the site for software recommendations). We require questions to be narrow in scope so that they can be objectively answered, rather than discussed. A better format for your question would be to ask things like "Why is the RSA-OAEP padding scheme used",  "Why/how does the RSA-OEAP padding scheme work", etc. You can use the "edit" link below the question to make changes. On another note: If someone links to a resource, consider reading it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Direct use of textbook RSA for encryption is very insecure. For example, a guess of the plaintext can be checked: if what's encrypted is a name on the class roll, enciphering all names on the class roll until getting the ciphertext breaks confidentiality. There are several other attacks.

That motivates RSA-OAEP. It turns textbook RSA, a hash, and a source of random bits, into a demonstrably secure encryption scheme. Encryption of message $M$ first transforms $M$ into padded message $X$ by mixing it with random bits and applying reversible transformations with the hash; then enciphers $X$ into $X^e\bmod N$, that is per textbook RSA encryption. Decryption starts by textbook RSA decryption, yielding $X$; then the padding is undone, yielding $M$ or an error indication.

I essence, the distribution of $X$ is random enough that textbook RSA becomes secure. A proof of that can be made for the strongest definition of security of a cipher, [IND-CCA2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_indistinguishability), and under some hypothesis:

- the RSA problem of finding a random $X$ given $X^e\bmod N$ is hard;
- the hash is undistinguishable from a public function selected at random;
- the source of random bits is indistinguishable from one producing uniformly random and independent bits;
- a decryption device given a cryptogram only outputs the correct plaintext or an error indication (it does not leak any other information).

A (highly technical) reference proof is in Eiichiro Fujisaki, Tatsuaki Okamoto, David Pointcheval, and Jacques Stern's [*RSA-OAEP Is Secure under the RSA Assumption*](https://www.di.ens.fr/david.pointcheval/Documents/Papers/2004_joc.pdf), in [Journal of Cryptology, 2004](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00145-002-0204-y). A more gentle text is David Pointcheval's [*How to Encrypt Properly with RSA?*](ftp://ftp.di.ens.fr/pub/users/pointche/Papers/2002_cryptobytes.pdf), originally in [Cryptobytes 5n1, 2002](http://www.networkdls.com/Articles/crypto5n1.pdf).

The practical form of RSA-OAEP is named RSAES-OAEP and defined in [PKCS#1 v2.2](http://mpqs.free.fr/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp_EMC_Corporation_Public-Key_Cryptography_Standards_(PKCS).pdf#page=16).